# Weird bug in PHP, Spaces in Paths and Windows

Tags: php, windows, path, command-line-interface, space

I've got to fix this little bug. First, let's talk about a small fact:
In CLI on Windows, you can't run a program with a space in its path, unless escaped:

```
C:\>a b/c.bat
'a' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>"a b/c.bat"

C:\>
```

I'm using proc_open...proc_close in PHP to run a process (program), example:

```
function _pipeExec($cmd,$input=''){
    $proc=proc_open($cmd,array(0=>array('pipe','r'),
        1=>array('pipe','w'),2=>array('pipe','w')),$pipes);
    fwrite($pipes[0],$input);
    fclose($pipes[0]);
    $stdout=stream_get_contents($pipes[1]); // max execusion time exceeded ssue
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    $stderr=stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);
    $rtn=proc_close($proc);
    return array(
        'stdout'=>$stdout,
        'stderr'=>$stderr,
        'return'=>(int)$rtn
    );
}

// example 1
_pipeExec('C:\\a b\\c.bat -switch');
// example 2
_pipeExec('"C:\\a b\\c.bat" -switch');
// example 3 (sounds stupid but I had to try)
_pipeExec('""C:\\a b\\c.bat"" -switch');
```

**Example 1**

- RESULT:  1
- STDERR:  'C:\a' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
- STDOUT:

**Example 2**

- RESULT:  1
- STDERR:  'C:\a' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
- STDOUT:

**Example 3**

- RESULT:  1
- STDERR:  The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
- STDOUT:

So you see, either case (double quotes or not) the code fails.
Is it me or am I missing something?

Comment: Shot in the dark, but can you try switching quote types? (`"` to `'`)

Comment: I have no experience in this, but in the command prompt you run "a b/c.bat" and in PHP you call "C:\a b\c.bat" including the path inside the quotes. Perhaps calling C:\"a b\c.bat" works?

Comment: @Pekka, I get the same as Example 3; it seems single quotes aren't container characters like double quotes.

Comment: @deltreme, that didn't work as well.

Comment: Another shot in the dark: Escape the spaces in the path with \ (e.g. `C:\\a\ b\\c.bat -switch` )

Comment: Did you try the simplest? C:\\"a b"\\c.bat

Comment: Viper that seems to work nicely. I'm confused as to why though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most unfortunately, the fix doesn't work as expected, however Pekka's first suggestion gave me an idea:

```
$file='C:\a b\c';
$cmdl='/d /b /g';

if(strtolower(substr(PHP_OS,0,3))=='win') // if windows...
    $file='cd '.escapeshellarg(dirname($file)).' && '.basename($file);

_pipeExec($file.' '.$cmdl);
```

This is platform-specific, and I hope I don't have to fix this over linux as well. So far it works well!

Comment: hi there, trying to use your solution in my code, and discovered there's a syntax error. you've got a dangling ) at the end of line 5. i'd fix it, but there's a minimum character limit on edits. cheers

Comment: This is a good workaround. I don't see any reason why this would fail on linux.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of solving this is by putting additional double quotes at the beginning and the end of the command.

```
$process = 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe';
$arg1 = 'C:\\Path to File\\foo.js';

$cmd = sprintf('"%s" %s', $process, escapeshellarg($arg1));
if (strtolower(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'win') {
    $cmd = '"'.$cmd.'"';
}

_pipeExec($cmd);
```

I have found this solution on https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49139
It looks weird, but hey - it's Windows... :D

Comment: That solution is weird, but it works and is more sane than cd'ing to the directory just to run a command.

Comment: Beware that is_executable does not work for paths inside quotes.

Comment: If you are using proc_open (as in the OP's post), then on Windows using the "other_options" parameter of proc_open with a value of array('bypass_shell' => true) means that the whole command does NOT need to be wrapped in " (but you do still need to escape the \ (as in \\\) and also quote the paths including spaces (as in "C:\\Program Files\\"). Using bypass_shell also means there is one less cmd.exe process in use (and a conhost.exe process too on W7 - perhaps on W8 & W10 too, don't know)

Answer (score 0):

This is strage.

Untested workaround ideas:

- Use a temporary environment variable:

  ```
  exec('SET ENVPATH="C:\a b"');
  proc_open('%ENVPATH%\c.bat' ....
  ```

  (no idea whether this will work for proc_open)
- Use the 8.3 filename if that can somehow be fetched in PHP - would certainly be doable using another `exec()`
- `proc_open()` has an option to bypass `cmd.exe` - might be worth a try in case the filesystem somehow handles the quotes differently
- Try escaping the quotes `\"`

Comment: The bypass cmd.exe gave me an idea: `cmd "C:\\a b\\c.bat"`

Comment: proc_open has an argument to pass in env variables better to use that.

Comment: @Christian ah, interesting. Might work. Maybe try also `call` @Viper good point!

Comment: Nevermind my earlier comment. My issue is not with `cmd.exe`; I'm actually running programs not batch files (eg: C:\ b\c.exe). Both have the same issue (but of course programs do not rely on cmd.exe).

Comment: OK, that "worked" but I lost control over the process, so, no fix yet :(